# Syslog-ng log template \\011 character

Tags: syslog-ng

I have a problem with syslog-ng. I want to make syslog-ng to format the logs like below:

```
template("$YEAR-$MONTH-$DAY\\011$HOUR:$MIN:$SEC\\011$HOST\\011$MSGHDR$MSGONLY\n")
```

But it logs without the "\". Just "011". Example:

> Expected: 2012-11-28\\01116:33:51\\011host_name\\011app_name[26250]:
>   message
>
> Happened: 2012-11-2801116:33:51011host_name011app_name[26250]: message

Edit:
I tried `template_escape()` and `flags()` methods, but no luck. Any ideas will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens if you insert two (e.g '\\') ?

Comment: I'm sorry, I edited the post, there should be two '\'s ;)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [`template_escape()`](http://www.balabit.com/sites/default/files/documents/syslog-ng-ose-3.3-guides/syslog-ng-ose-v3.3-guide-admin-en.html/configuring_macros.html) option.

Comment: I tried it, but unfortunately no luck.